# Can a travel agent redeem Air Arabia credit on my name for someone else?

Tags: refunds

A few months back my AirArabia flight was canceled. As per their policy, they won't give a refund. Instead, they have given me a credit of the same amount for a year. Since I am not in the situation to redeem it. Can partner TravelAgent somehow redeem it for someone else?

Comment: Credits are usually (though not always) not tied to anyone specific. The credit probably came with detailed terms and conditions explaining how it can be used, what does that say?

Comment: That is not correct, credits _are_ usually tied to the person getting them. The airline doesn’t want a grey market for credits / unused tickets, so they are nailed to the person.

Answer (score 3):

Typically not. If on doubt, read the terms and conditions that came with the refund. They spell out the rules including convertibility, expiration date, etc.

Comment: I thought authorized airline partners may have special privileges to redeem credit on behalf of the ticket owner. Although, the airline has a clear policy of "no refund"

Comment: Most airlines have a clear policy of "squeeze as much money out of the customer as possible".